# Set form's name equal dragged and dropped file title vb

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a text editor in VB. My text editor can already read and write text files, but I want something better than that. When I drag and drop a .txt file on my .exe program, my program reads the context of the .txt file.
But the problem is that I want the [Form1.Text] to be the path of the file I have dropped. For example, when you open a file with Wordpad, you can see the name of the file on the top: **TextFile.txt - Wordpad**

And that's the code:

```
Private Sub ReadingText(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim arguments As String = Command()
    If arguments = String.Empty Then
        RichTextBox1.Text += vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Else
        Dim tempstr As String = arguments.Replace("""", "")
        Dim SR As New System.IO.StreamReader(tempstr)
        RichTextBox1.Text = vbCrLf & SR.ReadToEnd
        Try
            SR.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            RichTextBox1.Text += ex.ToString
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Could you help??

Comment: edit your headline to fit the question before it will be down-voted

Comment: Saying you want something "better" is pretty broad.  Be specific, it's very unlikely you will find any help here the way this question stands right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got the filename in your `tempstr` variable, just use it:

```
    Dim tempstr As String = arguments.Replace("""", "")
    Me.Text = tempstr & " - YourTextEditorNameHere"    
    Dim SR As New System.IO.StreamReader(tempstr)
```

If you don't want the full path, use [Path.GetFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
    Dim tempstr As String = arguments.Replace("""", "")
    Me.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(tempstr) & " - YourTextEditorNameHere"    
    Dim SR As New System.IO.StreamReader(tempstr)
```

And if you don't want the extension, use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    Dim tempstr As String = arguments.Replace("""", "")
    Me.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempstr) & " - YourTextEditorNameHere"    
    Dim SR As New System.IO.StreamReader(tempstr)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! That's exactly what I wanted.. :) I promise I will be more specific in the future..